# All my android projects have r.java related errors

Tags: android, sdk

For some reason my eclipse/android development environment has stopped creating the r.java files and wont read them in any of my projects. Should I just uninstall eclipse and all traces of it and the android sdk Ive been using and start fresh?

Ive been looking for the past couple hours for a fix but I cant find one at all that seems to work so any suggestions on the matter would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time I update my source I always do this:

- Refresh project
- Clean project
- Refresh project

Works every time (unless I have a build path issue, then Right Clicking and Doing `Android Tools->Fix project properties` usually works)

---

Having build errors can keep the R file from being generated, make sure you don't have any syntax errors.

Comment: All the projects that had errors in them were ones I had previously finished and just left open. They didnt have any build errors but for some reason the root project file in the browser shows the error. Its really a weird thing and Ive never seen this error before. Every open project in my eclipse browser shows an error and there are none

Answer (score 1):

Try touching (making non-changing edit) one of your .java files and seeing if it forces the R files to rebuild. This appears to be a bug with Android SDK / Eclipse integration.

Comment: I just imported the project I want to be working the most onto my laptop and it works fine on the set up I have on there.....it has to be a eclipse error.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me a lot. Two things to try.
1) Try to clean the project

If that doesn't work. This usually works for me.
1) In eclipse delete the project (BE SURE NOT TO DELETE THE SOURCE)
2) Close eclipse
3) Open eclipse
4) Add the project back via New Project from existing source

Comment: Just to see what kind of errors are happening I tried to export some of the projects I have. I get this error when trying to export whatever/bin/whatever.apk does not exist.  well thats obvious cause I cant build it. Also the r.java file finally appeared but even without any errors in it the root of the project shows an error.....infact all my open projects show an error.

Comment: You know I imported my projects into my other computer and they work fine there

Comment: It has to be either eclipse or the java package or android package

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

1. Make sure that "Build automatically" option is on (under Projects menu)
2. Clean your project
3. Refresh your project

Comment: this doesnt seem to work. I turned of the auto build and then cleaned all the projects and then they all had no errors so when i turned auto build back on it put the errors back

Comment: @James I didn't say to turn it off, make sure it is ON before cleaning and refreshing. BTW, what about the "gen" folder? Can you see it?

Comment: Yeah its there. for some reason though when I try to do all the suggested things it doesnt help. However I did import an earlier version of the app I was building in an apk like the error report said when I tried to export the project and it worked fine and the error went away so I think its some setting. Its like eclipse is looking for an apk that hasnt been created yet in the bin folder of the projects

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing parentheses from a string title that I had created.

I am a complete n00b so I did not think that adding () to a title would cause problems.